# Upload image using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading

I have a working php code to upload image in the database. Is it Possible to transform it to jquery? If so, what do I need to do? I am new to jquery btw. Thanks

This code works just fine. But I need to do it in jquery.

```
<form action = 'upload.php' method = 'post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="image" > <br>
    <input type= 'submit' value = 'Add' id = 'Add' name = 'Add'>

</form> 


<?php   
    if(isset($_FILES['image']))
    {
    $target_Path = "images/";
    $target_Path = $target_Path.basename($_FILES['image']['name'] );
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_Path );

    $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['Add']))
    {

        if($_POST["Add"] == "Add") 
        {
        $add = "Insert Into img(path) Values('$name')";
        $up = mysql_query($add);

            $status = "Upload success!";
            print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
            print 'alert(" '.$status.' ")'; 
            print '</script>';                  
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try a jquery plugin. For example, Plupload http://www.plupload.com/ works great and has neat features like upload progress

Answer (score 6):

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formupload">
    <input type="file" name="image"/> <br>
    <input type='submit' value='Add' id='Add' name='Add/>
</form>
```

1. You need to first setup a callback for the submit event of the form.

   ```
   $("#formupload").on("submit", upload_image);
   ```

   - JQuery selectors work a lot like CSS; `$("#formupload")` selects the element whose id is `formupload`.
   - `on` is used to register a handler for an event.
   - Here, we are setting up a handler(the upload_image function) for the `submit` event of the element whose id is `formupload`.
2. Make an AJAX call to the php script.

   ```
   function upload_image(event){

       event = event || window.event;

       // Prevent the default form action i.e. loading of a new page
       if(event.preventDefault){ // W3C Variant
           event.preventDefault();
       }
       else{ // IE < 9
           event.returnValue = false;
       }

       $.ajax({
           url: "upload.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: new FormData($('#formupload')[0]), 

           success : function(data){
               // Show success message
           },
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           cache: false
       });
   }
   ```

   - You can prevent the default action of form submission, which is to load the POST response, which is what the first few lines of the function is doing.
   - An AJAX call is made using `$.ajax` which is the jQuery utility for performing an AJAX call.
   - The `url` property is to be filled by that of your PHP script.
   - Since it is a file upload, specify the HTTP method as POST.
   - The `data` property is the payload of the POST request, which is the content of the file you are trying to upload.
   - You can specify the success callback using the `success` property, which is the function that will be called on completion of the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call instead to submit a form. You can use something like this as well:

> https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Although, you still need to have your php code in order to store the file in your server