# How to upload the a file(image) through Web-API and update the data with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to upload a image as Avatar photo to the server through the Web-API.

Anyone can explain how to insert the image URL into the data by current user id has token?

I have already done `$.getJSON (url,...` I can read and append them wherever I wanted.

I have something like this:

> user_id=1
>
> /api/images/upload_form/avatar
>
> /api/users/update_user_info

**1. How can I attach the image file and post it through Web-API with jQuery?**

**2. And How can I re-upload(update) the file?**

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
     $('#upload').on('click', function () {
     var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
     var form_data = new FormData();
     form_data.append('file', file_data);
     $.ajax({
             url: 'https://myurl/api/images/upload_form/avatar', // point to server-side controller method
             dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the server
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             data: form_data,
             type: 'post',
             success: function (response) {
                 $('#msg').html(response); // display success response from the server
                 },
             error: function (response) {
                 $('#msg').html(response); // display error response from the server
                 }
           });
     });
});
```

> user_id=1 << I need to add this key and value to the post url, but how?

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: For #1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283986/how-to-upload-image-through-jquery. For #2 the request would be roughly the same as #1, but exactly how you format it, and the type of request, would depend on the API you're calling.

Comment: Whose API are you using? "Web-API" is a generic term

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I have tried this code for days. I can only return the response the  with last_id but the user_id was undefined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those new guys who still struggling like I was:

**1. How can I attach the image file and post it through Web-API with jQuery?**

> Uploading the image but response: { 'user_id' of undefined } ?

Before you post the your request, you have to grab parameters form the URL.

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); // current URL 

console.log(urlParams.get('user_id')); // return token id or user id
```

and all you have to do is put this:

```
...
var user_data = urlParams.get('user_id'); // or token
form_data.append('user_id', user_data);
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://myurl/api/images/upload_form/avatar', 
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        ...
```

**2. And How can I re-upload(update) the file?**

Just upload another file!

Might not be the right way to do that, but works!